# Dual socket with single CPU power connection

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power

Is it harmful for a processor and/or motherboard if the motherboard is a dual socket motherboard, only one socket is filled with a (compatible) processor, but two processor power plugs are plugged into the motherboard?

Comment: Yes...Its harmful

Comment: Can you maybe explain what possible harm could be caused?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  for what purpose?

Comment: @mdpc First of all, just to gather some more information about computers, the more the better! Second, it doesn't really have any purpose other than removing the need to plug it in later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine.  If there is no processor installed on the motherboard, no power will be drawn from the PSU.